# MacOS: How can I insert a line into an XML file based on it's filename?

Tags: osx, filenames, xml

I don't have access to a pure linux box. I have a bunch of XML files that are missing a filename callout line. I need to insert that line at a specific place in the XML file and have the filename callout be generated off the filename of the XML file, with a small transform.

Example:

24ToLife_AFamilyDivided_191045_DANY.xml has

```
<description>Entrepreneur James overcame unconscionable childhood abuse before the sins of his past came back to haunt him.</description>
<media:rating>TV-14</media:rating>
```

I need it to read:

```
<description>Entrepreneur James overcame unconscionable childhood abuse before the sins of his past came back to haunt him.</description>
<media:content url="24ToLife_AFamilyDivided_191045.mpg" type="video/mpg" expression="full" />
<media:rating>TV-14</media:rating>
```

Comment: are you able to install xmlparsers?

Comment: How do you determine the url?  Will the type and expression be the same for each file?

Answer (score 1):

I've just written and tested in MacOS High Sierra:

```
#!/bin/sh

for fl in *.xml
do
    filename=$(echo $fl | cut -f 1 -d '.' | sed 's/_DANY$//')

    sed -i .orig '1a\
    <media:content url="'$filename'.mpg" type="video/mpg" expression="full" /> \
    ' $fl
done

ls *.xml     search in current directory
-i .orig     backup of original files with suffix
'1a ..'      insert into second line
```

BSD `sed` in MacOS have several differences from GNU `sed`, so the following expression must be written in separate lines:

```
'1a \        # backslash and newline
 some text'
```

Newline symbol `\n` doesn't recognised, so you should write:

```
'1a \
some text   # newline here
'
```

instead of:

```
'1a \
some text\n'
```

Usage:

```
yurijs-MacBook-Pro:sed yurij$ cat *.xml
<description>Entrepreneur James overcame unconscionable childhood abuse before the sins of his past came back to haunt him.</description>
<media:rating>TV-14</media:rating>
<description>Entrepreneur James overcame unconscionable childhood abuse before the sins of his past came back to haunt him.</description>
<media:rating>TV-14</media:rating>
yurijs-MacBook-Pro:sed yurij$ ./cli
yurijs-MacBook-Pro:sed yurij$ cat *.xml
<description>Entrepreneur James overcame unconscionable childhood abuse before the sins of his past came back to haunt him.</description>
<media:content url="24ToLife_AFamilyDivided_191045.mpg" type="video/mpg" expression="full" />
<media:rating>TV-14</media:rating>
<description>Entrepreneur James overcame unconscionable childhood abuse before the sins of his past came back to haunt him.</description>
<media:content url="tt.mpg" type="video/mpg" expression="full" />
<media:rating>TV-14</media:rating>
```

Comment: I know. It's just a habit from other scripts in which `files` variable was useful in rest script code.

Comment: `-i` works on MacOS HighSierra. I've just tested it

Comment: I retest `-i` and it works. But it works from script, not from console.

Comment: also op wanted the url to be: `"url="24ToLife_AFamilyDivided_191045.mpg"` however you are setting it to: `url="24ToLife_AFamilyDivided_191045_DANY.mpg"`.  The question is unclear.

Comment: Agreed about variables. Good suggestion. And I know why is it. I hurried with answer and I've just fixed it in answer. Thanks for suggestion. Also, try this script. It's really works.

Comment: Thanks for removing the parsing of `ls` however your answer still includes the `_DANY` which op is indicating should be removed.

Comment: I've just removed `_DANY`, retest `./cli` and pasted changes in answer. Thanks for correction! I would to know are you testing this script in your Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python script that should do what you want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: ascii -*-
"""insert_xml.py"""

import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

# Get the filename from the command-line
filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename, 'r') as xmlfile:

    # Parse the file
    soup = Soup(xmlfile.read(), "html.parser")

    # Search for "description" tags
    for element in soup.findAll("description"):

        # Check to see if the "media:content" element is missing
        if element and not element.find_next_sibling("media:content"):

            # If so, construct a new "media:content" tag
            new_tag = soup.new_tag('media:content')
            new_tag["url"] = filename
            new_tag["type"] = "video/mpg"
            new_tag["expression"] = "full"

            # Insert the "media:content" tag after the "description" tag
            element.insert_after(new_tag)

    # Print the modified XML document - one element per line
    for element in soup.findAll():
        print(element)
```

Here's what it looks like in action:

```
$ python insert_xml.py in.xml

<description>Entrepreneur James overcame unconscionable childhood abuse before the sins of his past came back to haunt him.</description>
<media:content expression="full" type="video/mpg" url="in.xml"></media:content>
<media:rating>TV-14</media:rating>
```